# How do I control agent plotting order to place certain agents on top of each other?

Tags: julia, agents.jl

I am trying to make a plot/animation of a model with mixed agents (green patches and uav agents) and would like the uav agents to be plotted on top of the patch agents. I attached what I have for my code and an image below. Some of the UAV agents are plotted on top of the patches, while others are plotted behind them. I am wondering if there is a solution to this.

One thought I have is that has to do with the scheduling of the agents.

```
function agent_color(a)
    if a isa Patch
        color = "#007500" # get_color(a.prob_burn)
        if a.status == :on_fire
            color = :red
        elseif a.status == :burnt
            color = :gray55
        end
    elseif a isa UAV
        color = :blue
    else
    end
    color
end

const uav_polygon = Makie.Polygon(Point2f[(-.5,-.5), (1,0), (-.5,.5)])

function uav_marker(u::UAV)
    t = atan(u.vel[2], u.vel[1])
    shape = rotate_polygon(uav_polygon, t)
    return shape
end

function agent_shape(a)
    if a isa Patch
        shape = :hexagon
        if a.status == :on_fire
            shape = :circle
        elseif a.status == :burnt
            shape = :rect
        end
        
    elseif a isa UAV
        shape = uav_marker(a)
    else

    end
    shape
end


figure, _ = Agents.abmplot(forest; ac = agent_color,as = 24, am = agent_shape, scatterkwargs = (strokewidth = 0.1,), figure = (;resolution = (500,500)))
```

[image: Example of what I am trying to avoid]

I looked to see if I could find any examples of people doing this but was not able to. Closest thing would be rewriting it as a model step for the patches, but the nature of the hexagonal grid makes it difficult (unless I were to rewrite my entire model).

Comment: My intuition is that the scheduler will determine this ordering. Then looking at docs for `Schedulers.ByID()` and `Schedulers.ByProperty(property)` might help. If this doesn't help, the ordering might be the internal order in a Dict of agents. Hope this helps.

Comment: After looking at the code/docs a bit, I think you might want to add `container = OrderedDict` or `container = Vector` when calling `StandardABM` to create a model. If no agents are deleted, the latter is better. In both cases, the order of the agents in the container might be the display order, and can be manipulated as such.

Comment: `container = Vector` worked but `container = OrderDict` led to the same outcome as before. The plotting order is determined by the ID order in the model, which isn't always the same as 1 through n agents. I am not sure of the best way to handle this agents end up being deleted though but I am sure there is a way to change the order during initialization. Thank you @DanGetz

Comment: In the case of a Vector container (and perhaps OrderedDict too), there might be the option to permute the agents manually. But this needs to be tested, as some might depend on the order staying constant (though this sounds far-fetched)